# Programmatically assign a value prop to inputs through an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to assign the onChange and value props (controlled input) by passing them in an object through destructuring.

The function getInputProps() returns the onChange and value props

```
getInputProps = name => {
    return {
        value: this.state.data[name],
        onChange: this.handleInput
    }
}
```

The input element consumes these props through destructuring

```
<input {...getInputProps('myInput')} />
```

However, that doesn't work, and I guess it's because the value is being passed as a 'value' and not a 'reference' to the state variable. It works when I put the value directly as a prop. What are my alternatives to pass all the necessary input props in an object?

EDIT: The handleInput function is working, when I omit the 'value' prop everything works as expected. It's the value that is problematic. When it is passed this way, it passes the actual value (which is none) to the HTML5 value parameter, and it is not dynamic anymore. When I omit 'value' in the object, then the user input is correctly set in the state (which is what the handleInput does), but changing the state doesn't change the value of the input.

Comment: What do you mean by `that doesn't work`? Is the value not assigned to input field or the change to input field is not reflected?

Comment: Please add your handleInput function!

Comment: Also, if you have errors, it'd be a good idea to post them

Comment: I think he means that his onchange is not changing the input value?

Comment: Please not that if your errors comes from ubounded `this` context within the handleInput function it is quite normal and this should probably be done at construction time.

Comment: Works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/mm2lqq4rj8

Comment: The problem should be in how you call this.setstate in your handleInput function. With your getInputProps is nothing wrong. @Zakaria

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the solution. It is a simple stupid mistake. I was setting the name of the input and the 'name' passed to the function to different values. And the handleInput functions changes the state based on the actual name of the input.

Comment: In that case just delete the question since it's unlikely to help anybody else